# connect() failed (111: Connection refused) Error triying to proxy pass from nginx to local hosted service

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, openresty

I have a dockerised nginx server that i am trying to proxy pass to a service. I wanted to test the connectivity locally. Have both the service containers running locally on different ports

Nginx server: 127.0.0.1:8080 and service to proxy pass hosted on : 127.0.0.1:50204

Trying to proxy pass nginx to the local host in config as below

```
location = /health/live {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:50204/health/live;
        proxy_pass_request_body on;
    }
```

Please advice me whats wrong here. Can nginx really proxy pass to localhost?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you've published the port of the service (`-p 50204:50204`).
2. Replace `127.0.0.1` in the nginx proxy with the address of the docker host -- check `docker network inspect bridge | grep Gateway`. It's `172.17.0.1` by default.

Alternatively, use `docker-compose` -- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.